# Вызвать функцию главного потока

Tags: qt, c++

Нужно из функции Worker.work() вызвать асинхронно функцию MainWindow.updateAfterHandle

Есть класс Worker, он находится в дополнительном потоке:

```
class Worker : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    Worker(std::shared_ptr<ImageHandler>& handler);

private:
    std::shared_ptr<ImageHandler> handler;

public slots:
    void work()
    {
        this->handler->startHandler();
        // Этот сигнал будет присоединён к слоту
        // updateAfterHandle(Worker* worker) класса MainWindow (см. ниже)
        // и видимо он объект класса MainWindow главного потока помещает в
        // дополнительный поток
        // мне нужно как-то сообщить главному потоку, что дополнительный
        // отработал
        emit finished(this);
    }

signals:
    void finished(Worker* worker);
};
```

Клаcс Processes управляет множеством потоков.

```
class Processes : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    void addThread(std::shared_ptr<Worker>& worker);
    void runThread(std::shared_ptr<Worker>& worker);

public slots:
    void removeThread(Worker* worker);

private:
    QMap<std::shared_ptr<QThread>, std::shared_ptr<Worker>> processes;

signals:
    void handled(Worker* worker);
};

void Processes::addThread(std::shared_ptr<Worker>& worker)
{
    std::shared_ptr<QThread> thread(new QThread());

    worker->moveToThread(thread.get());
    connect(thread.get(), SIGNAL(started()), worker.get(), SLOT(work()));

    this->processes.insert(thread, worker);
}

void Processes::runThread(std::shared_ptr<Worker> &worker)
{
    std::shared_ptr<QThread> thread = processes.key(worker);
    thread->start();
}

void Processes::removeThread(Worker* worker)
{
    std::shared_ptr<QThread> thread;

    // Нахожу нужный поток.
    // ...

    // Здесь почему то замирает. Хотя это дополнительный поток
    thread.get()->wait();

    this->processes.remove(thread); 
}
```

Далее функция инициализации объекта класса Worker и запуск потока

```
void MainWindow::on_actionAdd_Noise_triggered()
{
    std::shared_ptr<ImageHandler> handler(new AddNoiseHandler());    
    std::shared_ptr<Worker> worker(new Worker(handler));

    // Поле класса MainWindow: Processes processes;
    processes.addThread(worker);

    connect(worker.get(), SIGNAL(finished(Worker*)), this, SLOT(updateAfterHandle(Worker*)));
    processes.runThread(worker);
}

void MainWindow::updateAfterHandle(Worker* worker)
{
    // ...
    // Вызывает ошибку
    this->processes.removeThread(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Всё правильно реализовал. Только ошибка в функции Processes::removeThread();

Нужно так:

```
void Processes::removeThread(Worker* worker)
{
    // ...
    thread.get()->quit();
    thread.get()->wait();

    this->processes.remove(thread); 
}
```